# Grouping and numbering items in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a column to a dataframe in python/pandas as follows:

```
| MarketID  | SelectionID |   Time   | SelectNumber |

| 112337406 | 3819251.0   | 13:38:32 |            4 |

| 112337406 | 3819251.0   | 13:39:03 |            4 |

| 112337406 | 4979206.0   | 11:29:34 |            1 |

| 112337406 | 4979206.0   | 11:37:34 |            1 |

| 112337406 | 5117439.0   | 13:36:32 |            3 |

| 112337406 | 5117439.0   | 13:37:03 |            3 |

| 112337406 | 5696467.0   | 13:23:03 |            2 |

| 112337406 | 5696467.0   | 13:23:33 |            2 |

| 112337407 | 3819254.0   | 13:39:12 |            4 |

| 112337407 | 4979206.0   | 11:29:56 |            1 |

| 112337407 | 4979206.0   | 16:27:34 |            1 |

| 112337407 | 5117441.0   | 13:36:54 |            3 |

| 112337407 | 5117441.0   | 17:47:11 |            3 |

| 112337407 | 5696485.0   | 13:23:04 |            2 |

| 112337407 | 5696485.0   | 18:23:59 |            2 |
```

I currently have the market ID, Selection ID and Time, I want to generate the SelectNumber column, which represents the time order in which the particular selectionID appears within a particular MarketID. Once numbered all other iterations of the same selection ID within that MarketID need to be numbered the same. The MarketID will always be unique, but the same selectionID can appear in more than 1 MarketID.

This has got me stumped, any ideas?

Comment: First of all, what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried the following, but it just numbers each iteration of the SelectionID df['SelectNo'] = df.sort_values('Suggest Time').groupby(['BF_MarketID','BF_SelectionID'],sort=False).cumcount()+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need the combinations of 'MarketID' and 'SelectionID' in order of occurrence, so lets sort on the time.
Then, for each 'MarketID' get the unique 'SelectionID's and number them in order of occurrence (already ordered, because df is ordered on column time). Secondly, the combination of number 'MarketID' and 'SelectionID' together with the order will be used later to set the numbers.

I'll give you two solution to the first part:

```
dfnewindex = df.sort_values('Time').set_index('MarketID')
valuesetter = {}
for indx in dfnewindex.index.unique():
    selectionid_per_marketid  = dfnewindex.loc[indx].sort_values('Time')['SelectionID'].drop_duplicates().values
    valuesetter.update(dict(zip(zip(len(selectionid_per_marketid)*[indx], selectionid_per_marketid), range(1, 1+len(selectionid_per_marketid)))))
```

100 loops, best of 3: 3.22 ms per loop

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values('Time')
valuesetter = {}
for mrktid in df_sorted['MarketID'].unique():
    sltnids = df_sorted[df_sorted['MarketID']==mrktid]['SelectionID'].drop_duplicates(keep='first').values
    valuesetter.update(dict(zip(zip(len(sltnids)*[mrktid], sltnids), range(1, 1+len(sltnids)))))
```

100 loops, best of 3: 2.59 ms per loop

The boolean slicing solution is slightly faster in this case

The output:

```
valuesetter

{(112337406, 3819251.0): 4,
 (112337406, 4979206.0): 1,
 (112337406, 5117439.0): 3,
 (112337406, 5696467.0): 2,
 (112337407, 3819254.0): 4,
 (112337407, 4979206.0): 1,
 (112337407, 5117441.0): 3,
 (112337407, 5696485.0): 2}
```

For the second part, this dict is used to generate a column, i.e. SelectNumber. Again two solutions, the first uses multiindex, the second groupby:

```
map(lambda x: valuesetter[x], df.set_index(['MarketID', 'SelectionID']).index.values)
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop

```
map(lambda x: valuesetter[x], df.groupby(['MarketID', 'SelectionID']).count().index.values)
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.59 ms per loop

the multiindex seems to be the fastest solution.

The final, up to this point, fastest answer:

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values('Time')
valuesetter2 = {}
for mrktid in df_sorted['MarketID'].unique():
    sltnids = df_sorted[df_sorted['MarketID']==mrktid]['SelectionID'].drop_duplicates(keep='first').values
    valuesetter2.update(dict(zip(zip(len(sltnids)*[mrktid], sltnids), range(1, 1+len(sltnids)))))
df_sorted['SelectNumber'] = list(map(lambda x: valuesetter[x], df.set_index(['MarketID', 'SelectionID']).index.values))
```

Comment: Thanks Daan, I will try this out

Comment: Hey Daan, The first solution is hanging, there's a few millions rows but i wouldn't expect it to take as long as it is. It gets stuck at the for loop

Comment: Good point, forgot to check the time. I've put the fastest solution on top.

Comment: The shorter solution seems to be numbering in the same way my first attempt did, counting each iteration of a SelectionID within a MarketID, rather than numbering each iteration of a SelectionID the same.

Comment: The valuesetter2 dict seems to have the correct values in it but I get the following message in the SelectNumber column: <map object at 0x14f524e48>

Comment: my bad, I ran this on python 2.7, use a cast to list on the map: list(map(...)), I've also updated the answer.

Comment: Great thanks Daan, got this working, really appreciated!

Comment: glad to hear that @RicHep365!